# Get group clicked in OnGroupClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I retrieve the group clicked in a OnGroupClickListener of a ExpandableListView.

I have tried parent.getItemAtPosition(groupPosition) and it return groups and childs so I think I must convert the groupPosition to a absolute position in the adapter, but I don't know how to do it.

```
new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                Item item= parent.getItemAtPosition(groupPosition);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

        Object object = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(groupPosition);

        ....
        ....

        return true;
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Could you proved an explanation as to why this should work so the OP can understand why?

Comment: The method `getItemAtPosition()` returns the data associated with both the group AND its children. To get the individual group/child object of an `ExpandableListView`, you need a reference to its `Adapter` and then you need to call either `getGroup()` or `getChild()` as the case may be ... :)